# 'HELP' with MySQL Results and PHP Coding

Tags: php, mysql

I am totally new to MySQL and PHP. I am making a website which displays MySQL results and then there is a select option allowing the viewer to choose how he wants the results sorted and then he is taken to another page with sorted results.

Here is my code for select function:

```
<div id="query">
        <label style="font-weight:bold;display:inline;">Sort By:</label>
                <select id="selection">
                            <option value="">Choose to sort...</option>
                            <option value="?sort=ranking">Ranking</option>
                            <option value="?sort=price_asc">Price: Low to high</option>
                            <option value="?sort=price_desc">Price: High to low</option>
                            <option value="?sort=title_asc">Title: A to Z</option>
                            <option value="?sort=title_desc">Title: Z to A</option>
                </select>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("selection").onchange = function() {
                if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
                    window.location.href = this.value;
                }        
            };
        </script>
        </div>
```

And here is the code for alteration of the Query:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM `AhopData` WHERE `Item` = 999";
```

"For some reason this isn't working. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank You"

Comment: You have to actually do something with the query.  First you have to open a connection to the database, then execute the query, then return and display the results.

Comment: limit goes after order by

Comment: You are right, Kevin O'Brien. I have not shown that part here, but that is in the original code. Thank You for your advice though.

Comment: Can you add examples (`var_dump()`'s) of a successful query, an unsuccessful query (the actual query strings, not the results) and the table structure?

Comment: As currently presented, your question makes no sense at all. How are the HTML and PHP code you've presented here even related? What isn't working? There's no way we can answer a question without even knowing what you're asking about.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP should read the starter tutorials/documentation for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try with LIMIT after ORDER BY Clause

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM `GamesData` WHERE `Ranking` <=20";

if ($_GET['sort'] == 'ranking')
{
    $Query .= " ORDER BY Ranking ASC";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'price_asc')
{
    $Query .= " ORDER BY Price ASC";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'price_desc')
{
    $Query .= " ORDER BY Price DESC";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'title_asc')
{
    $Query .= " ORDER BY Title ASC";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'title_desc')
{
    $Query .= " ORDER BY Title DESC";
}
$Query .= " LIMIT $limit";
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but again the sorted results don't appear.

Comment: Are you sure to get value in this $_GET['sort'] variable?

Comment: Why you want to delete this question?